Isekai manga about a man who ends up in another world and resolves a conflict between people living in a village and lizardmen living in a lake
Trying to find a specific isekai manga about a man who ends up in another world. I don't remember much, but at some point he resolves a conflict between people living in a village by a lake and lizardmen living in the lake. He also contracts with the deity turtle for the lizardmen after he wins a race against it. Later on, he enters a dungeon where he contracts with the bear king and defeats a weird goblin/gnome evil creature to save the bear queen, who also contracts with him.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Is he primarily a farmer, gifted with some sort of universal farming tool by the good who isekaied him?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Read it in January I think. Not a farmer, he's a merchant. Full black

There is no harem

solving a lizardman in a lake with a city reminds me of "Fun Territory Defense by the Optimistic Lord".  but the contracting of all the king animals sounds like a different manga that i've read but dont remember the title of.

It might be Isekai Nonbiri Nouka aka Farming Life in Another World

During the final years of his life, Hiraku Machio remained confined to a hospital bed with a terminal illness until he finally passed away. Taking pity on the unfair life he lived, a god decides to reincarnate Hiraku in another world where he can live as he pleases. Wanting to try farming in this new life, he is bestowed with an all-in-one "Almighty Farming Tool" that can transform into any useful implement he wishes. Hiraku is then transported to a forest seemingly far from civilization. Here, he plans to build and farm everything from scratch—gradually developing the lifeless area into a thriving new society.

I haven't found any slam dunk details, but he deals with lizardmen early in the webnovel (no mention of a turtle deity) and then later has to deal with a Bear King (no mention of a Bear Queen unfortunately).

Sorry I read that one. It not it since in the one I'm looking for the guy travels around and is a merchant
